# window.setTimeout needs to work even when user is in a different tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus, settimeout, requestanimationframe

So I'm making a game that earns points over time, even if the user isn't actually focused on the window the game is running in.  I'm using the setTimeout() and requestAnimationFrame() functions in javascript, and I'm running into an issue.

```
    //main game loop
    var FPS = 30;
    tick();
    function tick() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            window.requestAnimationFrame(tick);
            //draw everything
            draw();
            //do stuff
            ...stuff...
        }, Math.round(1000/FPS));
    }
```

The problem I'm running into ONLY occurs when the user focuses on a different tab.  The game still runs if the window is stowed, or if another window is on top of it.  This tells me it has nothing to do with the OS, rather, the browser.  And I've found it to be universal across browsers as well.  I need the game to run even when the player is using another tab, how do I accomplish that?  If there is an event specific to changing tabs, or if there is an alternative and reliable timer function, that would be fine.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Browsers throttle setTimeout calls to a maximum of 1 per second when a tab is hidden to maximize performance on active tabs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout#Inactive_tabs

If the browser(s) you're targeting support web workers, you could run your timeout function in a web worker and bypass this throttle.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample web worker that will run more than once per second when a tab is hidden. Unfortunately web workers are not supported in all browsers.

```
var blob = new Blob([
    "onmessage = function(e) { setTimeout(function(){postMessage('draw now'); },100)}"]);

// Obtain a blob URL reference to our worker 'file'.
var blobURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

var worker = new Worker(blobURL);
worker.onmessage = function(e) {
  draw();
  worker.postMessage('start timer');
};
worker.postMessage('start timer'); // Start the worker.
```

Working example here. Open the console to watch the count increment even when your tab is hidden.

http://jsfiddle.net/vu9bp/2/